# Find/grep statement code filter

Tags: unix

I need to generate a list of IFS files that contain a given string
("iim"). (IFS is the IBM System i database) I need to search directory /linoma/goanywhere/projects
recursively.  I've been able to do this with a combination of the FIND
and GREP commands in QSHELL:

find /linoma/goanywhere/userdata/projects -type f -exec grep -lRF "iim"
'{}' ';'

Here's the rub:  there is a subdirectory I want to ignore
(/linoma/goanywhere/userdata/projects/demo).  How would I modify my
find/grep statement to exclude the demo folder?

Comment: qshell? What OS are you using? Good luck.

Comment: this is on the as/400 we still have one of them.

Comment: Did BRPocock's solution work? Do you still need ideas for this? Good luck.

Comment: Depending on how often you have to do this, and how much overhead is involved in processing the demo subdir, maybe you should just add a pipe at the end to `| grep -v '/userdata/projects/demo'`. Good luck.

Answer (score 2):

`find /linoma/goanywhere/userdata/projects -( -type f -and -not -path '/linoma/goanywhere/userdata/projects/demo/**' -) -exec grep -IRF 'iim' '{}' ';'`
should work for GNU `find`, I believe. If your local `find` doesn't support that syntax, you might also brute-force remove by appending `| grep -v /linoma/goanywhere/userdata/projects/demo`